# Unable to Locate MySQL Server

Tags: networking, mysql

So there is this ancient legacy server running MySQL somewhere in our office. I can connect remotely using:

```
# mysql -u someuser -p -h ancientserver.domain.com
```

I see the tables I expect. However, when I connect to the server via ssh like this:

```
# ssh root@ancientserver.domain.com
```

then run a:

```
# ps -ef | grep mysql
```

I don't see a mysql server process. Other exploration confirms mysql server is not installed ancientserver.domain.com.

**Is it possible that this ancientserver.domain.com is being used a proxy--just passing the MySQL requests on to another server? If so, how could I determine the ip of the actual server on which the MySQL server is installed?**

While connected, I have run a:

```
mysql> @@hostname
```

and the hostname is indeed different from that of ancientserver.domain.com.

Comment: ancientserver.domain.com could be running haproxy or some other proxy app so check for a config file in the server.

Answer (score 3):

I would be tempted to run tcpdump on your client and see if your client is contacting `ancientserver.domain.com`.  If it is, connect to that, and again tcpdump.  See if you have some kind of port forwarding or tunneling going on.  Packet captures probably should give you an idea.

```
tcpdump -qni any port 3306 # watch for port 3306 traffic on any interface.
```

If there are any firewalls or routers between you and that host, check on those to see if your packets are being redirected before they get to the named destination.  A tcpdump on the named destination should be empty if this is what is happening.

Check your iptables rules `iptables -nL -t nat`.  Look for anything that looks like it may be a simple tcp proxy.  The netstat command @knowhy should do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `netstat -tulpn | grep 3306` to identify the process using the mysql port `3306`.

There is a [MySQL proxy](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) but my guess would be that the MySQL process is running under a different name and that is why you can't find it via `ps`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Ran this command as root and nothing was returned. Also doing a "locate mysql" returns very few results--none of which are associated with a typical mysql server install.